# Download Input From Textbox

Tags: javascript, html

I have been trying to make a form that when the user clicks a button it downloads the input from the 2 text inputs and saves them to a file. My code is:

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
var username = document.forms['login'].username.value
var password = document.forms['login'].password.value
function createResult(){

    result = 
    `
    username=${username}
    password=${password}

    `;

    download(document.forms['login'].name.value+".txt",result)
}
</script>
<body>
<form id="login">
<input type="text" id="username">
<input type="text" id="password">
</form>
<button onclick="createResult()" />
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You cannot access a dom element until its been loaded - this is never the case for naked code in the <head> element

Comment: What is `${username}` ? This is not valid syntax

Comment: What is `download()`?